# Using MySQL as a job queue

Tags: mysql, algorithm, queue, job-scheduling

I'd like to use MySQL as a job queue. Multiple machines will be producing and consuming jobs. Jobs need to be scheduled; some may run every hour, some every day, etc.

It seems fairly straightforward: for each job, have a "nextFireTime" column, and have worker machines search for the job with the nextFireTime, change the status of the record to "inProcess", and then update the nextFireTime when the job ends.

The problem comes in when a worker dies silently. It won't be able to update the nextFireTime or set the status back to "idle".

Unfortunately, jobs can be long-running, so a reaper thread that looks for jobs that have been inProcess too long isn't an option. There's no timeout value that would work.

Can anyone suggest a design pattern that would properly handle unreliable worker machines?

Comment: Tough one.  Can long running jobs be required to periodically update a "still in status" column with the time they updated it?  And require that happen once every X minutes?  Then the reaper could say "if you went beyond X minutes without an update, whack!"

Comment: Or perhaps a better design would be to somehow have the job queue itself query the jobs to determine their status.  (Kind of a listener model.)  A job would have to know how to respond to a status query.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. Kind of like a heartbeat signal. Industrial controllers do that. It's possible, but it would mean all my job processers would have to have some kind of internal loop to do the update. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: There are already well established task queue servers like RabbitMQ. Why not use one of those, rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but please read this article: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you/

Comment: Linkrot, now the blog post is at https://www.engineyard.com/blog/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this

When a worker fetches a job it can add it's process-id or another unique id to a field in the job

Then in another table every worker keeps updating a value that they are alive. When updating the "i'm alive" field you check all other "last time worker showed sign of life". If one worker is over a limit, find all the jobs it is working on and reset them.

So in other words the watchdog works on the worker-processes and not the jobs themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Using MySQL as a job queue generally ends in pain, as it's a very poor fit for the usual goals of an RDBMS. User 'toong' already linked to https://www.engineyard.com/blog/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you, which has a lot of interesting stuff to say about it. Unreliable workers are only one of the complications.

There are many, many systems for handling job distribution, mostly distinguished by the sophistication of their queueing and scheduling capabilities. On the simple FIFO end are things like Resque, Celery, Beanstalkd, and Gearman; on the sophisticated end are things like GridEngine, Torque/Maui, and PBS Pro. I highly recommend the new Amazon Simple Workflow system, if you can tolerate reliance on an Amazon service (I believe it does *not* require that you be in EC2).

To your original question: right now we're implementing a per-node supervisor that can tell if the node's jobs are still active, and sending a heartbeat back to a job monitor if so. It's a pain, but as you are discovering and will continue to discover, there are a lot of details and error cases to manage. Mostly, though, I have to encourage you to do yourself a favor by learning about this domain and build the system properly from the start.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make sure that jobs are idempotent, and allow more than one worker to start a given job.  It doesn't matter which worker completes the job, or if more than one worker completes the job; since the jobs are designed in such a way that multiple completions are handled gracefully.  perhaps workers *race* to supply the result, and the losers find that the slot that will hold the result is already full, so they just drop them.

Another option is to not have big jobs.  Break long running jobs into intermediate steps, if the job takes longer than (say) 1 minute, store the intermediate results as a new job (with a link to the old job in some way), so that the new job can be queued again to do another minute of work.

Comment: Yeah, that is a possibility. Overlapping jobs are probably ok.